# Why the transition of diamond to graphite is so slow?

Tags: thermodynamics

Why the transition of diamond to graphite is so slow? Do I have to worry that one day I'll wake up and see graphite instead of my diamond?

Comment: The transition is so slow because chemistry. If that doesn't convince you, think of the prominent diamonds which have been known for centuries; they didn't turn to graphite, not a little bit.

Comment: There's another way to look at it. Diamond has an adamantane structure, while graphite has a hexagonal sheet structure. Imagine trying to change the structural arrangement of $6.023×10^{23}$ atoms. Even nature can't do such a difficult task so fast!